# Inno Setup skip memo page if empty

Tags: inno-setup

I am using the Modular Dependencies scripts found here : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20868/NET-Framework-Installer-for-InnoSetup to install .Net and VC++.

Now, it's all well and good, and has allowed me to reduce my installer size by about 6MB.

But I want to provide the user with the fastest setup possible, and when the user already has all the necessary dependencies, he is presented with an empty "memo" screen. That's really less than optimal, and I'd wish to at least skip this step if there is nothing.

I can test if there is any component to install using `if (GetArrayLength(products) = 0) then`, but I can't find out where to place this test.

In the `InitializeSetup` function I can't find how to tell "skip this screen", and in the `ShouldSkipPage` function, I can't find how to tell "skip the Memo page".

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be this way:

```
[Code]
function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  // skip page when we are on the ready page and the memo is empty
  Result := (PageID = wpReady) and (WizardForm.ReadyMemo.Text = '');
end;
```

Comment: Spot-on and insanely fast answer, as always :) thank you ! :)